# bbPress Private Forum Redirect to Login

Tags: php, wordpress, bbpress

**Edit:** Here is how to do it if you use a slug prefix for your forums (change "forums" if using a different slug).  This code also redirects the user to login and back to the page they were on for private pages / posts.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'private_content_redirect_to_login', 9);
function private_content_redirect_to_login() {
  global $wp_query,$wpdb;
  if (is_404()) {
    $private = $wpdb->get_row($wp_query->request);
    $host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $path = dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $forums = "forums";
    $location = wp_login_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    if( 'private' == $private->post_status  ) {
      wp_safe_redirect($location);
      exit;
    }
    }
    if(strpos( $path, $forums ) !== false){
      wp_safe_redirect($location);
      exit;
  }
}
```

I am trying to get WordPress to redirect a user from the default 404 page that is shown when a user is not logged in but are trying to see a private topic. I'm very new to PHP and I cannot figure out why the below code is not working, it is also suppose to redirect them to the page they were trying to see after login. I've seen this question asked a few times but no answers.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'private_content_redirect_to_login', 9);
function private_content_redirect_to_login() {
  global $wp_query,$wpdb;
  if (is_404()) {
    $private = $wpdb->get_row($wp_query->request);
    $location = wp_login_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    if( 'private' == $private->bbp_private_post_status  ) {
      wp_safe_redirect($location);
      exit;
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) about `template_redirect`: _"This action hook executes just **before** WordPress determines which template page to load"_ . As I read it, this action will only be executed when the page is about to be redirected. WP's default 404 doesn't redirect the user, which means that `is_404()` won't be true.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Magnus! It looks like because it executes beforehand and it does call this is_404, because I was able to get it to work with the below answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I am using:
    `// Redirect private bbPress forum to specific page.
    add_action('template_redirect', 'private_content_redirect_to_login', 9);
    function private_content_redirect_to_login() {
       global $wp_query,$wpdb;
       if (is_404() and !is_user_logged_in()) {
        $host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $path = dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $forums = "forum";
        $location = "redirect to the URL of your choice";
        }
        if(strpos( $path, $forums ) !== false){
          wp_safe_redirect($location);
          exit;
      }
    }`

Btw
Here is a tutorial:
https://www.easywebdesigntutorials.com/hide-buddypress-pages-and-bbpress-forums-from-not-logged-in-users/